# A more suitable java component for entering the values of a matrix

Tags: java, javafx

My program resolves the LU decomposition. I need to make an interface where the user can enter the dimension and the input matrix. I tried to use an editable table, but it seems to me a bit complicated because of the dynamic columns... is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `List` of `JTextField`s arranged in a matrix with the `GridLayout`.

I don't know if this would be less complicated than a dynamic `JTable`.

Comment: Okey, thanks anyway. Now I know for sure it's done with JTable.